# change the color of navigation bar of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone

I m trying to change the color of navigation bar of UINavigationController by using

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

in the below given code but its not working.

```
 #import "uitextviewAppDelegate.h"

#import "uitextviewViewController.h"

@implementation uitextviewAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[uitextviewViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];  

[navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

[_window addSubview:navigationController.view];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Can anyone tell why it is not changing the color of the navigation bar of the UINavigation Controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at these two lines:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

What connects the first `navigationController` with `self.navigationController`?

Nothing, as far as I can tell.

You need to assign `self.navigationController` to `navigationController`.

Something like:

```
self.navigationController = navigationController;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I wonder why i was not able to point it out. Appreciate it.